# GIT - Custom design per client

Tags: git, github

I'm beginner with Git and I'm wondering, for a project, if there is a way to use the master branch as a root and at the same time use branch to customize websites per client.

What I have now is a general code wich can be duplicate on differents hosts. Then I have 1 config file with informations like :

- Client Name
- Logo
- Email
- Etc.

I guess I could do it with differents technics (Ex : 1 SQL table/client) but I feel interested to know if there is the possibility to use something like :

- 1 branch master
- 1 branch to develop
- 1 branch for client #1
- 1 branch for client #2
- Etc...

Clients branchs would customize master and/or develop.

The project is not gonna be big, not hundreds and hundreds branchs, it's more about 15~20 clients.

So all the website is gonna be 99% the same, just has some files could be customize between clients.

I did some tests and researchs but nothing really work... just close to what I want but never get it. Now I'm wondering if that's just possible to do it with Git...

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. That is a legitimate use. Git is awesome because just about anything that works is fine with it. I am not referring of course to bad practices that may screw you over for other reasons.

Comment: Thanks Mad Physicist! So now I feel I'm not far from the truth! Just need to practice Git a little bit more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GIT to solve the issue, You need to create a master branch and all for all client websites you can cut a branch from master branch.

So if you need to need to make any changes to the core code and if it should get reflected in all the websites, you could make that change in master and then do a
`git merge master` while you are in the sub branch

A cleaner way would be to use a master branch and develop branch, use master for all websites and then use a config json/xml file and configure each website.

Comment: Hello Geo Paul and thanks for your answer! So what I understand in the first solution is I create a sub-branch from my master. Then I commit the config file inside this new branch. Later I will don't need to often update this file but each each time I update the master, I will need to merge master inside EACH client's branch? For the 2nd solution I don't really see how to proceed, if you could light me on it. Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry I would like to upvote but stackoverflow is requesting more reputation.